# hrwros_gazebo package gives me error when I do 'catkin build'. Does anyone understand error ? I am using gazebo 9 on ubuntu 18

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Straight dump of the error message:

```
<< hrwros_gazebo:make /home/arslan/hrwros_ws/logs/hrwros_gazebo/build.make.003.log
In file included from /home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:40:0:

/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/include/hrwros_gazebo/plugins/ARIAC.hh:280:13: error: ‘math’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘tanh’?
     public: math::Pose pose;
             ^~~~
             tanh

/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/include/hrwros_gazebo/plugins/ARIAC.hh: In function ‘std::ostream& ariac::operator<<(std::ostream&, const ariac::KitObject&)’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/include/hrwros_gazebo/plugins/ARIAC.hh:268:33: error: ‘const class ariac::KitObject’ has no member named ‘pose’
       _out << "Pose: [" << _obj.pose << "]" << std::endl;
                                 ^~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc: At global scope:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:81:23: error: ‘math’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘tanh’?
               public: math::Box dropRegion;
                       ^~~~
                       tanh
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:84:23: error: ‘math’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘tanh’?
               public: math::Pose destination;
                       ^~~~
                       tanh

/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc: In member function ‘bool gazebo::VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject::operator==(const gazebo::VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject&) const’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:60:25: error: ‘const class gazebo::VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject’ has no member named ‘dropRegion’
                   this->dropRegion == _obj.dropRegion && \
                         ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:60:44: error: ‘const class gazebo::VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject’ has no member named ‘dropRegion’
                   this->dropRegion == _obj.dropRegion && \
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:61:25: error: ‘const class gazebo::VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject’ has no member named ‘destination’
                   this->destination == _obj.destination;
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:61:45: error: ‘const class gazebo::VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject’ has no member named ‘destination’
                   this->destination == _obj.destination;
                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~

/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc: In function ‘std::ostream& gazebo::operator<<(std::ostream&, const gazebo::VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject&)’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:72:30: error: ‘const class gazebo::VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject’ has no member named ‘dropRegion’
                 _out << _obj.dropRegion << std::endl;
                              ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:73:44: error: ‘const class gazebo::VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject’ has no member named ‘destination’
                 _out << "  Dst: [" << _obj.destination << "]" << std::endl;
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc: In destructor ‘virtual gazebo::VacuumGripperPlugin::~VacuumGripperPlugin()’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:199:53: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetRunning’; did you mean ‘Running’?
   if (this->dataPtr->world && this->dataPtr->world->GetRunning())
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                     Running
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:201:38: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetPhysicsEngine’; did you mean ‘SetPhysicsEnabled’?
     auto mgr = this->dataPtr->world->GetPhysicsEngine()->GetContactManager();
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                      SetPhysicsEnabled
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::VacuumGripperPlugin::Load(gazebo::physics::ModelPtr, sdf::ElementPtr)’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:213:51: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetName’; did you mean ‘Name’?
   this->dataPtr->node->Init(this->dataPtr->world->GetName());
                                                   ^~~~~~~
                                                   Name
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:218:29: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetPhysicsEngine’; did you mean ‘SetPhysicsEnabled’?
       this->dataPtr->world->GetPhysicsEngine()->CreateJoint(
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                             SetPhysicsEnabled
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:266:15: error: ‘gazebo::math’ has not been declared
       gazebo::math::Vector3 min = dropRegionElem->Get<math::Vector3>("min");
               ^~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:276:15: error: ‘gazebo::math’ has not been declared
       gazebo::math::Vector3 max = dropRegionElem->Get<math::Vector3>("max");
               ^~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:298:7: error: ‘math’ has not been declared
       math::Box dropRegion = math::Box(min, max);
       ^~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:299:7: error: ‘math’ has not been declared
       math::Pose destination = dstElement->Get<math::Pose>();
       ^~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:300:64: error: ‘dropRegion’ was not declared in this scope
       VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject dropObject {type, dropRegion, destination};
                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:300:64: note: suggested alternative: ‘dropRegionElem’
       VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject dropObject {type, dropRegion, destination};
                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                                dropRegionElem
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:300:76: error: ‘destination’ was not declared in this scope
       VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject dropObject {type, dropRegion, destination};


                                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:300:76: note: suggested alternative: ‘sigaction’
       VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject dropObject {type, dropRegion, destination};
                                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                            sigaction
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:300:87: error: too many initializers for ‘gazebo::VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject’
       VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject dropObject {type, dropRegion, destination};
                                                                                       ^
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/SideContactPlugin.cc: In destructor ‘virtual gazebo::SideContactPlugin::~SideContactPlugin()’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/SideContactPlugin.cc:35:18: error: ‘DisconnectWorldUpdateBegin’ is not a member of ‘gazebo::event::Events’
   event::Events::DisconnectWorldUpdateBegin(this->updateConnection);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:324:38: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetPhysicsEngine’; did you mean ‘SetPhysicsEnabled’?
     auto mgr = this->dataPtr->world->GetPhysicsEngine()->GetContactManager();
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                      SetPhysicsEnabled
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/SideContactPlugin.cc: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::SideContactPlugin::Load(gazebo::physics::ModelPtr, sdf::ElementPtr)’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/SideContactPlugin.cc:52:33: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetName’; did you mean ‘Name’?
   this->node->Init(this->world->GetName());
                                 ^~~~~~~
                                 Name
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc: In member function ‘void gazebo::VacuumGripperPlugin::OnUpdate()’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:411:54: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Model’ has no member named ‘GetWorldPose’; did you mean ‘SetWorldPose’?
     auto objPose = this->dataPtr->dropAttachedModel->GetWorldPose();
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                      SetWorldPose
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:415:20: error: ‘const class gazebo::VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject’ has no member named ‘dropRegion’
         dropObject.dropRegion.Contains(objPose.pos))
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:422:22: error: ‘const class gazebo::VacuumGripperPluginPrivate::DropObject’ has no member named ‘destination’
           dropObject.destination);
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc: In member function ‘void gazebo::VacuumGripperPlugin::OnContacts(ConstContactsPtr&)’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:450:31: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetEntity’
         this->dataPtr->world->GetEntity(_msg->contact(i).collision1()));


                               ^~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:452:31: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetEntity’
         this->dataPtr->world->GetEntity(_msg->contact(i).collision2()));
                               ^~~~~~~~~


/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc: In member function ‘bool gazebo::VacuumGripperPlugin::GetContactNormal()’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:483:31: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetEntity’
         this->dataPtr->world->GetEntity(name1));

                               ^~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/SideContactPlugin.cc:109:39: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetSimTime’; did you mean ‘SetSimTime’?
   this->lastUpdateTime = this->world->GetSimTime();
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~
                                       SetSimTime
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:493:31: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetEntity’
         this->dataPtr->world->GetEntity(name2));
                               ^~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc: In member function ‘void gazebo::VacuumGripperPlugin::HandleAttach()’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:517:49: error: ‘math’ has not been declared
       this->dataPtr->modelCollision->GetLink(), math::Pose());
                                                 ^~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/SideContactPlugin.cc: In member function ‘bool gazebo::SideContactPlugin::FindContactSensor()’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/SideContactPlugin.cc:131:20: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetName’; did you mean ‘Name’?
       this->world->GetName() + "::" + link->GetScopedName() + "::" + this->contactSensorName;
                    ^~~~~~~
                    Name
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc: In member function ‘bool gazebo::VacuumGripperPlugin::CheckModelContact()’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:584:59: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Link’ has no member named ‘GetWorldPose’; did you mean ‘SetWorldPose’?
     auto gripperLinkPose = this->dataPtr->suctionCupLink->GetWorldPose().Ign();
                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                           SetWorldPose
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:585:5: error: ‘math’ has not been declared
     math::Vector3 gripperLinkNormal =
     ^~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc:587:24: error: ‘gripperLinkNormal’ was not declared in this scope
     double alignment = gripperLinkNormal.Dot(this->dataPtr->modelContactNormal);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/ProximityRayPlugin.cc: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::ProximityRayPlugin::Load(gazebo::sensors::SensorPtr, sdf::ElementPtr)’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/ProximityRayPlugin.cc:110:76: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetEntity’
       this->link = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<physics::Link>(this->world->GetEntity(linkName));
                                                                            ^~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/SideContactPlugin.cc: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::SideContactPlugin::CalculateContactingLinks()’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/SideContactPlugin.cc:185:67: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetEntity’
       boost::static_pointer_cast<physics::Collision>(this->world->GetEntity(*collision));
                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/ProximityRayPlugin.cc: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::ProximityRayPlugin::OnNewLaserScans()’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/ProximityRayPlugin.cc:126:60: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetSimTime’; did you mean ‘SetSimTime’?
     msgs::Set(this->stateMsg.mutable_stamp(), this->world->GetSimTime());
                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                            SetSimTime
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/SideContactPlugin.cc: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::SideContactPlugin::ClearContactingModels()’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/SideContactPlugin.cc:213:25: error: ‘math’ has not been declared
     model->SetWorldPose(math::Pose(0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0));
                         ^~~~
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/SideContactPlugin.cc: In member function ‘bool gazebo::SideContactPlugin::TimeToExecute()’:
/home/arslan/hrwros_ws/src/hrwros_gazebo/src/plugins/SideContactPlugin.cc:224:47: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::World’ has no member named ‘GetSimTime’; did you mean ‘SetSimTime’?
   gazebo::common::Time curTime = this->world->GetSimTime();
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~
                                               SetSimTime
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/VacuumGripperPlugin.dir/src/plugins/VacuumGripperPlugin.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/VacuumGripperPlugin.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ProximityRayPlugin.dir/src/plugins/ProximityRayPlugin.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ProximityRayPlugin.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SideContactPlugin.dir/src/plugins/SideContactPlugin.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SideContactPlugin.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
cd /home/arslan/hrwros_ws/build/hrwros_gazebo; catkin build --get-env hrwros_gazebo | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=6,7 -j; cd -
...............................................................................
Failed     << hrwros_gazebo:make                          [ Exited with code 2 ]
Failed    <<< hrwros_gazebo                               [ 17.8 seconds ]     
[build] Summary: 15 of 16 packages succeeded.                                  
[build]   Ignored:   1 packages were skipped or are blacklisted.               
[build]   Warnings:  None.                                                     
[build]   Abandoned: None.                                                     
[build]   Failed:    1 packages failed.                                        
[build] Runtime: 19.5 seconds total
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333001/hrwros_gazebo-package-gives-me-error-when-i-do-%27catkin-build%27.--does-anyone-understand-error-?-i-am-using-gazebo-9-on-ubuntu-18./) by [hafizas101](https://answers.ros.org/users/44506/hafizas101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If `hrwros_gazebo` is one of the packages from the edX MOOC "Hello (Real) World with ROS", then unfortunately you cannot build those right now on Melodic.

The MOOC uses a special deployment image with Kinetic and Gazebo 7 for exactly this reason: the plugins and packages used have a hard dependency on Gazebo 7, and they must be updated to build with Gazebo 9.

Perhaps there are other users on the forum of the MOOC that have figured this out, but at this time the advice would be to either use the Singulary image that is provided by the MOOC, or install Kinetic.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hafizas101](https://answers.ros.org/users/44506/hafizas101/) on 2019-09-16**:
Yes you are right about the package. I have heard that the same course will start again on 15th January, 2020. I request you to update your future course so that melodic users can also benefit from your course.
Thanks for your response. I helped.